# Listview inside TabHost (ActivityGroup)

Tags: android, listview, android-tabhost

I have created listview activity.Code below:

```
public class List extends Activity {

  ListView listView ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_android_example);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android",
                "iPhone",
                "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry",
                "WebOS",
                "Ubuntu",
                "Windows7",
                "Max OS X"
        };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

activity_list_view_android_example.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this list activity I try add to tabhost activity.
Code below:

```
public class Main extends ActivityGroup{

TabHost tabHost;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        try
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost1);
            tabHost.setup(getLocalActivityManager());
            this.tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

            TabHost.TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1");
            photospec.setIndicator("Tab1");
            Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this,Lista.class );
            photospec.setContent(photosIntent);

            TabHost.TabSpec photospec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2");
            photospec2.setIndicator("Tab2");
            Intent photosIntent2 = new Intent(this,Lista.class );
            photospec2.setContent(photosIntent2);

            TabHost.TabSpec photospec3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3");
            photospec3.setIndicator("Tab3");
            Intent photosIntent3 = new Intent(this,Lista.class );
            photospec3.setContent(photosIntent3);


            tabHost.addTab(photospec);
            tabHost.addTab(photospec2);
            tabHost.addTab(photospec3);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            String a= ex.getMessage();
            String b="sdds";
        }

    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <TabHost
                android:id="@+id/tabhost1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <TabWidget
                        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        />
                <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        >
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>
</ScrollView>
```

So when I run my application something is cutting my listview,so as result my device display this.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/iqbm37lfedklafg/zakladki_lista_zle.png.jpg

As result my application I want to receive this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qdjqgnwqjtjvf3d/zakladki_lista_dobre.png.jpg

How solve my problem?? I will be grateful if somebody help me solve my problem. Sorry if this problem is simple, but I am begginer and I can't solve this.

Comment: I am confused about your code. Isn't it supposed to be: `this,List.class` not `this,Lista.class`? There is no `Lista` class defined here....

Answer (score -1):

Set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` (instead of `wrap_content`) for the `ListView`. You want it to fill the whole vertical space of its parent. ListViews cannot use `wrap_content` for height.

You should also remove the root `ScrollView`. Nested scrolls are not possible in Android (and a ListView has an implicit scroll).